# How to calculate gradient of an array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, statistics, regression

I have multiple arrays in `numpy` which I have plotted and I want to see which of these graphs have been increasing overall or decreasing. I know `numpy` has a built in gradient function but that gives it for each point. Would calculating the mean of the resulting gradient array give me an accurate representation of if my graphs were decreasing or increasing?

e.g

These are some of my arrays:

`n1=[6.2, 5.0, 6.6, 5.7, 8.3, 8.5, 7.9, 6.7, 8.0, 8.3, 8.6, 8.3]`

`n2=[13.8, 10.4, 9.4, 12.4, 12.8, 10.9, 11.0, 11.0, 11.7, 14.5, 13.8, 14.2]`

Currently I am doing this:

```
m_n1=np.mean(np.gradient(n1))
m_n2=np.mean(np.gradient(n2))
```

Which gives:

`m_n1` as 0.1125

and `m_n2` as -0.092

Can I say that the graph for `n1` is positive and the graph for `n2` is negative?

Answer (score 1):

Taking the mean of the gradients is not a robust way to determine trends in your data. If you graph your data there is an obvious upward trend and as you point out the mean of the gradients would be negative for the second case. Using your example below we can plot the data, look at the trends, and the variability in the gradients.

You can see that using a trend line is a more robust way of determining whether your data is increasing or decreasing, given that the trend line actually represents your data. The gradients on the otherhand amplify the sub trend scale variability and now include positive and negative numbers that will offset in the mean.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Define the example data
n1=np.array([6.2, 5.0, 6.6, 5.7, 8.3, 8.5, 7.9, 6.7, 8.0, 8.3, 8.6, 8.3])
n2=np.array([13.8, 10.4, 9.4, 12.4, 12.8, 10.9, 11.0, 11.0, 11.7, 14.5, 13.8, 14.2])

# arbitrary time dimension, assume fixed delta 
tim = np.arange(0,len(n1))

# get linear trend lines
m1, b1 = np.polyfit(tim, n1, 1)
m2, b2 = np.polyfit(tim, n2, 1)


fig=plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))

ax1=plt.subplot(121)
ax1.plot(tim,n1,c='C0',lw=2,label='n1')
ax1.plot(tim,n2,c='C1',lw=2,label='n2')
ax1.plot(tim,m1*tim+b1,ls='dotted',c='C0',lw=2,label='n1 slope=%1.2f'%m1)
ax1.plot(tim,m2*tim+b2,ls='dotted',c='C1',lw=2,label='n2 slope=%1.2f'%m2)
ax1.legend()


ax2=plt.subplot(122)
ax2.plot(tim,np.gradient(n1),c='C0',lw=2,label='n1 gradient mean=%1.2f'%np.mean(np.gradient(n1)))
ax2.plot(tim,np.gradient(n2),c='C1',lw=2,label='n2 gradient mean=%1.2f'%np.mean(np.gradient(n2)))
ax2.axhline(0,c='black')
ax2.legend()

plt.show()
```